# Dynamically assign controller and action to a form inside a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a scenario where I need to render 3 different forms inside 3 jQuery-UI tabs, the structure of the forms and their model is identical, but I need to post the forms to a different controller and Action method depending on which tab the form is contained in. I've create a Partial View containing that form. Obviously I can create 3 different partial view posting to 3 different controllers however that seems very inefficient.

I'm wondering if its possible to somehow tell the Partial View to change the controller and action that the form contained in it posts to based on the tab it's contained in.

Something like:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">New Question </a><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/FAQ.png")" /></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">New Idea  </a> <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/idea.png")" /></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">New Bug</a> <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/bug-icon.png")" /></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    @Html.Partial("_NewQuestionPartial")//this form posts to: Controller=Home and Action=Question
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    @Html.Partial("_NewQuestionPartial")//I want this form to post to: Controller=Support and Action=Idea
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    @Html.Partial("_NewQuestionPartial")//I want this form to post to: Controller=Support and Action=NewBug
  </div>
</div>
```

If I could somehow pass a variable to the partial view I can then set the action and controller with jQuery.

Is this at all possible? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is your `_NewQuestionPartial` strongly typed?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass ViewBag fields (or better still, properties on your ViewModel) to the partial view that contains the name of the controller and view to post back to, and then in the view, insert these values into the appropriate arguments of the BeginForm helper.

In the main view:

```
@{
<div id="tabs">
     <ul>
        ...
     </ul>
     <div id="tabs-1">
          ViewBag.Controller = "Home";
          ViewBag.Action = "Question";
          Html.Partial("_NewQuestionPartial");
     </div>
     <div id="tabs-2">
          ViewBag.Controller = "Idea";
          ViewBag.Action = "Question";
          Html.Partial("_NewQuestionPartial");
     </div>
     <div id="tabs-3">
          ViewBag.Controller = "Idea";
          ViewBag.Action = "NewBug";
          Html.Partial("_NewQuestionPartial");
     </div>
</div>                
}
```

And in the partial view:

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm((string)ViewBag.Action, (string)ViewBag.Controller))
        {
            ...
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean assign those values in the controller that returns the partial view? The problem is I don't know exactly which form the user will chose when I'm returning the partial view from the controller. I need to be able to choose and assign the controller and action client side (in the view) since only at that point will i be able to know which controller and action i need to assign to the partial view.

Comment: If your main view renders a page with three tabs (divs) as in your markup fragment above, and the user selects a view by clicking on a tab you can simply pass the appropriate controller/action parameters to the PartialView each time you inject it. I have edited my code to make it clearer what I mean.

Comment: Just to clarify, the JQuery only has to be responsible for showing the right tab/form, not for supplying the action/controller values.

Comment: This is certainly a nice idea, but when I tried to implement it I found that since the tabs are rendered in order, the last ViewBag object to be assigned as the controller/action is assigned to all the other 3 forms, for example in your code the first and second tabs actions would be set to `NewBug` and their controllers will be `Idea`. Eventually I just ended up creating 3 different partial views for each form.